# Profile Edit View Different in Sandbox vs Production

Tags: profile, sandbox

I have just noticed today some weird behavior happening in my SF sandbox, when I try to edit a profile the page layout looks like :

[image]

Compared to the production standard one which is :

[image]

Is it possible the revert it back to normal, as I am not able to edit any system permissions either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: UI Profile Selection]Yes, you can change this setting in the User Interface and untick the Enable Enhanced Profile User Interface.