# Why on these 2 environments I have different profile view?

Tags: profile, administration, sandbox, configuration, system-admin

On my first environment, this is how I can review my System Administrator profile:

[image]

On my second environment, this is how I can review my profile:
[image]

Is there any way to switch the view from the second picture to the first picture? (or vice versa)
Is there any permission that can change what I can view in the profile?

How can I compare these profiles?
I mean: if I want to find "Assigned Apps" in the profile from the second picture, how can I find it? I tried finding this via ctrl + f -> "app" - but I can't find any setting for this.

I looked into this [Profile Edit View Different in Sandbox vs Production](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121386/profile-edit-view-different-in-sandbox-vs-production)
and I tried to go into setup -> User Interface - but I don't have that option: "Enable Enhanced Profile User Interface" available

Comment: The 1st org is using a so-called Enhanced Profile UI.  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_profiles_about_enhanced_ui.htm&type=5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a toggle view option for your requirements.
Go to "Setup" then "User Management Settings" and its the "Enhanced Profile List Views" toggle option.
Refresh your profile page and this should reflect!

Comment: Thanks! It works now